# API-key work on localhost but not from server

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I am making small YouTube playlist project and Im using Youtube api to get data. I have used "Key for server applications" for now and white listed my own ip address. This way I have gotten data from youtube. But now when I try to move it to my own server I dont get any data. I tried to add server's ip address to the key too but it didn't work. I used this PHP code to get server's ip

```
echo $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
```

My app is at dev.domain.com/app 
So I also tried to add second key which is "Key for browser applications". I added pattern like this

```
*.domain.com/*
```

But it didn't work either. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure:

1. Server key is definitely the one you want to choose when you work with PHP.
2. I checked `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];` on my server, it returns the IP that is associated with the domain name. So it should be just fine for you as well.

Can you provide the answer of the API, please? There's most likely some helpful information in it.